# How to select font awesome icons in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

```
        = link_to content_tag(:i, nil, class: 'fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x pull-right'), my_path(format: :js), remote: true
```

Above is my code and I want to select this link in jQuery to add some effects. How can I select it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of these classes: `fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x pull-right`,
e.g.: `$('.fa-plus-circle')` or `$('.pull-right')`.

Choose that class, which does not repeat in other elements, that you don't want to be affected by your script.

You can also define context: `$('.fa-plus-circle', '.parent-class-name')`, which is the class name of one of the link parent elements in order to be more specific in choosing right link.

Answer (score 0):

`$('a.fa-plus-circle')` will select *all* links that are using the `fa-plus-circle` class.

If you need something more specific to select that link and *only* that link, you'll need to add a more specific attribute to the link, such as an `id`.